# What package is to be installed in R for scatter plots with logarithmic binning?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, bins

I am trying to produce some high density scatter plots with R. What package should be installed for this? Or is there any other way to obtain the plots.

Comment: links to examples?  hexbin package springs to mind

Comment: @user, "Scatter plots" implies an xy plot, while "logarithmic binning" implies some type of histogram.    Can you be more specific on what type of plot you're looking for?

Comment: @bill_080 I am looking for a scatterplot, which has logarithmic binning. Logarithmic binning is to create bins such that the length of a bin is a multiple of the length of the one before it. And yes I had found hexbin package but I think thats not what I was looking for. Here is a link to a paper which has high density scatterplots done with logarithmic binning on page 10. citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/… I hope it helps to clarify

Answer (score 2):

If you really do want a log scaled scatterplot, then this is how to create them in each of the 3 plotting systems.

First, some data:

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = rlnorm(1e5), y = rlnorm(1e5))
```

In base graphics:

```
with(dfr, plot(x, y, log = "xy"))
```

In lattice graphics:

```
library(lattice)
p1 <- xyplot(y ~ x, dfr, scales = list(log = TRUE))
p1
```

In ggplot2 graphics (will need to install that package + dependencies):

```
library(ggplot2)
p2 <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_log10()
p2
```

Comment: Nice example, but not at all clear from the question whether this is what the OP wants ...

Comment: @Ben and Richie: Please see my comments on the question!

Comment: @Ben: please refer to one paper http://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/pub-et_10937.pdf , I am trying to produce some high density scatterplots with logarithmic binning as done in the paper on page 10. Please let me know how to produce these in R

Comment: I don't have time to work through this at the moment, but you (or perhaps another commenter) should be able to work it out using a combination of (1) `cut` applied with appropriate logarithmic breaks to your `x` and `y` variables; (2) `table` applied to these two derived variables; (3) `image` applied to this table with appropriate logarithmic breaks, or `melt` (from the `reshape` package) the table and plot with points, again colored appropriately ...

Comment: @Richie I tried your suggestions for base, lattice and ggplot2 graphics which I found is similar to just doing plot(log(x),log(y)) . IMHO your suggestions just takes log of the values in x and y and plots the scatter plot. But, I am looking for how to create logarithmic bins in the scatterplot. I found something on hexagonal plot using the library (hexbin), which is one way to define bins but not like logarithmic bins.

Comment: @user744121: did you try to work through my suggestions?  where did you get stuck? Feel free to edit your question above to show what you tried ...

Comment: @Ben, I am confused about how to specify logarithmic breaks in this command for cut, c1 <- cut(x, breaks = ), I think I am stuck in the first part only.

Comment: e.g. `c1 <- cut(x,breaks=10^seq(-5,1,by=0.5))` for 12 logarithmically spaced bins encompassing the range from 1e-5 to 10

Answer (score 1):

I've just been struggling with trying to plot these recently; and just ended up using the standard hist() function with a custom set of breaks:

```
x <- your data
nbreaks <- 50 # how many points do you want in your scatter plot
breaks <- exp(seq(log(min(x)), log(max(x)), len=nbreaks))
hh <- hist(x, breaks, plot=FALSE)
plot(hh$mids, hh$density, log="xy")
```

I.e. create an exponentially distributed set of breaks and generate the histogram, but manually plot the densities giving control over which axes are logged.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot2? - see examples for [geom_point](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_point.html) (using alpha) or [geom_hex](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_binhex.html)