# Scatterplot matrix with logarithmic axes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatterplot matrix from my dataset so that in the resulting matrix:

- I have two different groups based on

  - Quarter of the year (distinguished as the colours of points)
  - Day type (shape of points indicating, is it weekend or casual day between Monday and Friday)
- Logarithmic-scaled x and y axes.
- Values on axis tick labels are not logarithmic i.e. values should be shown on axes as integers between 0 to 350, not their log10 counterparts.
- Upper panel has correlation values for each quarter.

So far I've tried using functions:

1. pairs()
2. ggpairs() [from GGally package]
3. scatterplotMatrix()
4. splom()

But I haven't been able to get decent results with these packages, and every time it seems that one or more of my requirements are missing.

- With pairs(), I'm able to create the scatterplot matrix, but the parameter *log="xy"* somehow removes the variable names from the diagonal of the resulting matrix.
- ggpairs() doesn't support logarithmic scales directly, but I created a function that goes through the scatterplot matrix's diagonal and lower plane based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598174/what-package-is-to-be-installed-in-r-for-scatter-plots-with-logarithmic-binning) answer. Though the logarithmic scaling works on lower plane, it messes up the variable labels and value ticks.

Function is created and used as follows:

```
ggpairs_logarithmize <- function(a) { # parameter a is a ggpairs sp-matrix
        max_limit <- sqrt(length(a$plots))
        for(row in 1:max_limit) { # index 1 is used to go through the diagonal also
                for(col in j:max_limit) {
                        subsp <- getPlot(a,row,col)
                        subspnew <- subsp + scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()
                        subspnew$type <- 'logcontinous'
                        subspnew$subType <- 'logpoints'
                        a <- putPlot(a,subspnew,row,col)
                }
        }
        return(a)
}
scatplot <- ggpairs(...)
scatplot_log10 <- ggpairs_logarithmize(scatplot)
scatplot_log10
```

- scatterplotMatrix() didn't seem to support two groupings. I was able to do this separately for season and day type though, but I need both groups in the same plot.
- splom() somehow labels the axis tick values also to logarithmic values, and these should be kept as they are (between integers 0 and 350).

Are there any simple solutions available to create a scatterplot matrix with logarithmic axes with the requirements I have?

**EDIT (13.7.2012):** Example data and output were asked. Here's some code snippets to produce a demo dataset:

*Declare necessary functions*

```
logarithmize <- function(a)
{
        max_limit <- sqrt(length(a$plots))
        for(j in 1:max_limit) {
                for(i in j:max_limit) {
                        subsp <- getPlot(a,i,j)
                        subspnew <- subsp + scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()
                        subspnew$type <- 'logcontinous'
                        subspnew$subType <- 'logpoints'
                        a <- putPlot(a,subspnew,i,j)
                }
        }
        return(a)
}

add_quarters <- function(a,datecol,targetcol) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(a)) {
        month <- 1+as.POSIXlt(as.Date(a[i,datecol]))$mon
        if ( month <= 3 ) { a[i,targetcol] <- "Q1" }
        else if (month <= 6 && month > 3) { a[i,targetcol] <- "Q2" }
        else if ( month <= 9 && month > 6 ) { a[i,targetcol] <- "Q3" }
        else if ( month > 9 ) { a[i,targetcol] <- "Q4" }
    }
    return(a)
}
```

*Create dataset:*

```
days <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"),as.Date("2012-06-06"),"day")
bananas <- sample(1:350,length(days), replace=T)
apples <- sample(1:350,length(days), replace=T)
oranges <- sample(1:350,length(days), replace=T)
weekdays <- c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")
fruitsales <- data.frame(Date=days,Dayofweek=rep(weekdays,length.out=length(days)),Bananas=bananas,Apples=apples,Oranges=oranges)
fruitsales[5:6,"Quarter"] <- NA
fruitsales[6:7,"Daytype"] <- NA
fruitsales$Daytype <- fruitsales$Dayofweek
levels(fruitsales$Daytype) # Confirm the day type levels before assigning new levels
levels(fruitsales$Daytype) <- c("Casual","Casual","Weekend","Weekend","Casual","Casual","Casual
")
fruitsales <- add_quarters(fruitsales,1,6)
```

*Excecute (NOTE! Windows/Mac users, change x11() according to what OS you have)*

```
# install.packages("GGally")
require(GGally)
x11(); ggpairs(fruitsales,columns=3:5,colour="Quarter",shape="Daytype")
x11(); logarithmize(ggpairs(fruitsales,columns=3:5,colour="Quarter",shape="Daytype"))
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `pairs(log(dat))` as outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4748636/324364)?

Comment: pairs() does work for creating the scatterplot matrix, but unfortunately by calling e.g. pairs(log(data),col=palette[unclass(data$Quarter)],pch=c(4,19)[mod$Daytype]) the axis annotations are also now logarithmic. And as I stated, they are needed in the original form as integers between 0 and 350, not in their logarithmic values from 0 to ~6.

Comment: Could you show sample data and desired output? Handwritten one is sufficient.

Comment: Added an example dataset creation and plottings, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `pairs` stems from the use of user co-ordinates in a log coordinate system. Specifically, when adding the labels on the diagonals, `pairs` sets

```
par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
```

however, if you specify a log coordinate system via `log = "xy"`, what you need here is

```
par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1), xlog = FALSE, ylog = FALSE)
```

see [this post on R help](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e4/help/08/03/6405.html).

This suggests the following solution (using data given in question):

```
## adapted from panel.cor in ?pairs
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, cex.cor, quarter, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1), xlog = FALSE, ylog = FALSE)
  r <- rev(tapply(seq_along(quarter), quarter, function(id) cor(x[id], y[id])))
  txt <- format(c(0.123456789, r), digits=digits)[-1]
  txt <- paste(names(txt), txt)
  if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
  text(0.5, c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8), txt)
}

pairs(fruitsales[,3:5], log = "xy", 
      diag.panel = function(x, ...) par(xlog = FALSE, ylog = FALSE),
      label.pos = 0.5,
      col = unclass(factor(fruitsales[,6])), 
      pch = unclass(fruitsales[,7]), upper.panel = panel.cor, 
      quarter = factor(fruitsales[,6]))
```

This produces the following plot

[image: pairs plot on log coordinate system]

Comment: Thank you for your detailly explained solution! This works perfectly.